# HtmlWeb.LoadAsync not updating on refresh on WP7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to develop a free app that just screen scrapes another free-to-air web page and displays some figures nicely. This web page is refreshed periodically so I would like to have the ability to refresh the app while it is active, rather than reloading.

On load up it does its usual Initialize and then calls `HtmlWeb.LoadAsync("URL", DwnldComplete);` Then all it does is finds some inner text on some specific div tags.

My logic, albeit probably wrong, was to have a refresh button that just recalled the `HtmlWeb.LoadAsync("URL", DwnldComplete);` line to re-process the web page. However when I debug and step through, all it does it process the original page opened on load up. It doesn't actually go and fetch the updated page, I can check this because the web page has a date time stamp.

I tried refreshing on a console app with

```
HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlDocument doc = web.Load("URL");
```

and that works just fine. Maybe something to do with `LoadAsync`?

Then I thought maybe a new initialised HtmlWeb might help so I tried this to no avail.

```
HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
web.LoadCompleted += new EventHandler<HtmlDocumentLoadCompleted>(DwnldComplete);
web.LoadAsync("URL");
```

Here's the handler

```
void DwnldComplete(object sender,HtmlDocumentLoadCompleted  e)
    {
        if (e.Error == null)
        {
            HtmlDocument doc = e.Document;
            if (doc != null)
            {
              //Find text
            }
        }
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: So I found that `String.Format("Url?{0}",RandomNumber)` will cause a refresh of the cache or whatever it is, but the main website I try fails when you put the ?random at the end of the url so I can't use that method. Any ideas?